# Closure of Ball = Closed Ball in Normed Space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, normed-spaces

> Show that, in any normed space $(X, \Vert \cdot \Vert)$, $\overline{B_{\Vert \cdot \Vert} (x, r)}$ = $\hat{B}_{\Vert \cdot \Vert} (x, r)$, i.e. the closure of a ball is the closed ball, for all $x \in X$ and $r > 0$.

$\subseteq$ seems to be trivially true since the closure $\overline{B}$ is the smallest closed set containing $B$, so it has to be inside $\hat B$. The other way doesn't seem to be quite clear though.

$\hat B \subseteq \overline{B}$ means the elements of $\hat B$ has to be in $B$ or the set of limit points $B'$, since by definition $\overline{B} = B \bigcup B'$. But how does the norm come into play here? I don't think I can say "$\hat B$ is closed, so it contains all elements of $B$, $b \in B$'s accumulation points, and perhaps more. From what I understand, a norm is much more strict than a metric, so I don't think what I'm thinking can really be this general for normed spaces. How should I approach the $\hat B \subseteq \overline{B}$ part of the proof? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you approximate elements of norm exactly $r$ by elements with norm less than $r$?

Comment: Not in a normed space, right?

Comment: Certainly, in a normed space.

Comment: If we can approximate elements of norm $r$ by elements with norms less than $r$, then does that mean we can essentially approximate everything in $\hat B$?

Comment: Yes, that;s right.

Comment: So if we can measure all elements in $\hat B$, and $\hat B$ contains all elements of $B$ and $B’$ since it’s closed, then $\overline{B}$ must be inside $\hat B$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $D(x,r) = \{ y | \|x-y\| \le r \}$ and $B(x,r) = \{ y | \|x-y\| < r \}$.

We have $B(x,r) \subset D(x,r)$ for all $r$.
Since the norm is continuous we see that $D(x,r)$ is closed and hence $\overline{B}(x,r) \subset D(x,r)$.

Now suppose $y \notin \overline{B}(x,r)$. Since $\overline{B}(x,r)$ is closed
there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(y,\epsilon)$ does not intersect $\overline{B}(x,r)$ (and hence does not intersect $B(x,r)$). It follows that
$\|x-y\| \ge r + \epsilon$ and
so $y \notin D(x,r)$. Hence $D(x,r) \subset \overline{B}(x,r)$.

**Addendum**: To show why $\|x-y\| \ge r + \epsilon$:

Let $\phi(t) = t y +(1-t)x$. For $0 \le t_1 \le t_2 \le 1$ we have $\|\phi(t_2)-\phi(t_1)\| = (t_2-t_1) \|x-y\|$.

Note that $\phi(t) \in B(x,r)$ if $t \in [0,{r \over \|x-y\|})$ and
$\phi(t) \in B(y,\epsilon)$ if $t \in (1-{\epsilon \over \|x-y\|}), 1]$, and we must have $t_1={r \over \|x-y\|} \le t_2=1-{\epsilon \over \|x-y\|}$ since the balls do not overlap.

Finally $\|x-y\|= \|\phi(0)-\phi(1)\| \ge \|\phi(0)-\phi(t_1)\| + \|\phi(t_2)-\phi(1)\| = r+ \epsilon$.

**Another take**:

Consider $\phi(t)$ for $t \in [0,1]$. For the $t \in [0,{r \over \|x-y\|})$ part we have $\phi(t) \in B(x,r)$ and for $t \in (1-{\epsilon \over \|x-y\|}), 1]$ we have $\phi(t) \in B(y,\epsilon)$. The balls do not overlap, so the intervals $[0,{r \over \|x-y\|}), (1-{\epsilon \over \|x-y\|}), 1]$ are disjoint and the combined length of the intervals is ${r+ \epsilon \over \|x-y\|}$.

Since $\|\phi(t_2)-\phi(t_1)\| = (t_2-t_1) \|x-y\|$ for $0 \le t_1\le t_2 \le 1$ we see that
$\|x-y\|=\|\phi(1)-\phi(0)\| = (1-t_2)+(t_2-t_1)+(t_1-0)) \|x-y\| \ge (1-t_2)+(t_1-0) \|x-y\|$, and since $(1-t_2)+(t_1-0) = {r+ \epsilon \over \|x-y\|}$ we have the desired result.

Comment: Sir, please can you elaborate "since the norm is continuous we see that...... that is first part of your answer.

Comment: The inverse image of a closed set ($(-\infty, r]$) under a continuous map (the norm) is a closed set.

Comment: I can intuitively see why $||x-y|| \ge r + \epsilon$ follows from the preceding steps, but how would you go about making that part more formal?

Comment: @jwl: Let $p(t) = y+t (x-y)$. Let $t_1$ be such that $p(t_1)$ lies on the boundary of $B(y,\epsilon)$ and let $t_2$ be such that $p(t_2)$ lies on the boundary of $B(x,r)$. We must have $0 < t_1 \le t_2 < 1$ and we have $\|x-y\| = \|p(1)-p(t_2)\| + \|p(t_2)-p(t_1)\| + \|p(t_1)-p(0)\|$.

Comment: I am in thinking as the inverse image of the closed set $[0,r]$ is better than $(-\infty,r]$ in every sense.

Comment: @user519955: I don't understand the point of your comment.

Comment: @copper.hat You had said that $D(x,r)$ is closed since it is inverse image of a closed set $(-\infty,r]$ under a continuous function as I understand. I wanted to indicate it is inverse image of $[0,r]$ since norm is always positive and also many writers don’t accept $(-\infty,r]$ as a closed set.

Comment: Both are closed but since the norm is non negative it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @copper.hat Sir, what i can see is, if S= inverse image of $(-∞,r]$ then, $S=\{y\in X : ||y||\in(-∞,r]\}=\{y\in X: -∞<||y||≤r\}$ so that, $S=\{y\in X: ||y||≤r\}$ so by Continuity of norm $S$ is closed. But, then how it follows $D(x,r)=\{y\in X: ||y-x||≤r\}$ is closed? Please help

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi The function $y \mapsto \|y-x\|$ is continuous, and hence $\{y | \|y-x\| \in [r, \infty) \}$ is closed.

Comment: @copper.hat sir, first of all thank you so much for replying to such an old post. Sir i think this will be more better. The function $y \mapsto \|y-x\|$ is continuous, and hence as $\{y | \|y-x\| \in (-∞,r] \}$ is closed. (Since, $\{y | \|y-x\| \in (-∞,r] \}=\{y: -∞<||y-x||≤r\}=\{y: ||y-x||≤r\}=D(x,r)$ )

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi You are correct, I should have written $(-\infty,r]$.

Comment: To prove the first direction you don't need the norm, just the fact that the closure is minimal. For the second direction, it seems that the norm could be swapped for any metric. So it seems like this question is true for any metric. However, I know that there is a counter example to this, using the discrete metric. Therefore the properties of the norm must have played a role in this proof, but I don't see how..

Comment: @ngc1300 Good observation, the step you are looking for is the second last sentence. A simple counterexample is $X=\{1,2\}$ with the usual distance $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ and $r=1$.

Comment: @copper.hat I am having trouble following the conclusion on that line. My book has a similar problem, with the balls centered around 0 and radius 1. So $B_\epsilon(a) \cap B_1(0) = \emptyset$. Then for all $b \in B_1(0)$ $|| a - b || \geq \epsilon $. I need to use the fact that $|| b || < 1 $ and the only way I see how to do this is to write $1 + || a || > || b|| + || a || \geq || b - a || \geq \epsilon$. But this implies $|| a || > \epsilon - 1 $ which doesn't necessarily mean it is not in the closed ball.

Comment: @copper.hat Basically, I see how we can conclude $|| x - y || \geq r $ but why can we justify adding $\epsilon$ to the other side?

Comment: @ngc1300 If $B(x,r)$ and $B(y,\epsilon)$ do not intersect, then we must have $\|x-y\| \ge r + \epsilon$. Look at the straight line between $x,y$ and consider a point on the line that is not in either ball.

Comment: @copper.hat I can see it geometrically but I can't prove it directly. Maybe by contradiction?

Comment: Wtf I don't even see how to do it with contradiction. Feel like a fking idiot this should be  really simple

Comment: @ngc1300 I added an elaboration. Draw a little picture,  line between $x,y$ and two non overlapping balls around $x,y$ of radius $r,\epsilon$ respectively.

Comment: @ Thanks, now, it's clear why it only works for normed spaces. You know at one point I thought it had to come down to the scalar multiplication rule because that's really what differs a norm from a metric. But I really think that I wouldn't have been able to see that proof which annoys me.

Comment: @copper.hat Wait, now I'm confused again. Isn't the last step contradictory to the triangle inequality? The only way it wouldn't be is if it was strictly =, but then we would have $||x-y|| = r + \epsilon$.

Comment: No, the whole point is that the problem is reduced to a one dimensional one on the line through $x,y$. It will help to draw a picture.

Comment: Oh, right the end points are not same so it doesn't violate the triangle inequality. I see now. Since $ 0 \leq t_1 + (1 - t_2) \leq 1$ then $||x - y || \geq || x - y || (t_1 + (1 - t_2)) = t_1 || x - y || + (1 - t_2) || x - y || = || \phi (0) - \phi (t_1) || + || \phi (t_2) - \phi (1)|| $

Comment: @MFTSBU hopefully this helps you years later lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135609/discussion-between-ngc1300-and-copper-hat).

Comment: Better to keep questions here.

Comment: @copper.hat Sorry I'm back again with another question. Hope you're not annoyed. Still one thing I'm getting hung up on. I was looking at the line 'And we must have $t_1 = \frac{r}{|| x - y||} \leq t_2 = 1 - \frac{\epsilon}{|| x - y ||}$ since the balls don't overlap'. But this statement assumes exactly what we are trying to prove. $\frac{r}{|| x - y||} \leq 1 - \frac{\epsilon}{|| x - y ||} \implies r \leq || x - y || - \epsilon \implies r + \epsilon \leq || x - y ||$

Comment: @ngc1300 I added another few paragraphs. I suspect the point you are getting hung on is that $\phi(t)$ is on the straight line segment $[x,y]$ for $t \in [0,1]$ so if you have $0 \le s_1 \le s_2 \le \cdots \le t_m \le 1$ you have $\| \phi(s_m)-\phi(s_1)\| = \|\phi(s_m)-\phi(s_{m-1})\| +\cdots +\|\phi(s_3)-\phi(s_{2})\|+\|\phi(s_2)-\phi(s_{1})\|$.

Comment: I have the same question as ngc1300 in his last comment and do not understand how your comment addresses his. In the other few paragraphs (Another take) that you added, it seems to me that as soon as you state that intervals $\left[0,{r\over\|x-y\|}\right), \left(1-{\epsilon\over\|x-y\|}, 1\right]$ are disjoint, you have that $\|x-y\|\ge r + \epsilon$. Why do you proceed with the second paragraph?

Comment: @user0 Are you asking why I continued elaborating?

Comment: Yes.  Is the last paragraph necessary in each of your "Addendum" and "Another Take" to conclude that $\|x - y\|\ge r +\epsilon$?

Comment: @user0 No. Just an elaboration. From my perspective it follows from the fact that we are on a straight line in a vector space and the balls do not overlap.

Answer (score 3):

It's sufficient to show that $\hat{B}(x,r)\setminus B(x,r) \subseteq \overline{B(x,r)}$.

Let $y\in\hat{B}(x,r)\setminus B(x,r)$ and notice that $\|y-x\| = r$.

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $y_n\in B(y,1/n)\cap B(x,r)$ (why does such $y_n$ exist? Can you define it?).
Clearly $y_n\to y$, which shows that $y\in B(x,r)'$. Thus $y\in\overline{B(x,r)}$.

---

*Hint for existence of $y_n$:*
Since $B(x,r)$ is convex, $(1-t)x+ty\in B(x,r)$ for every $t\in[0,1)$.
You can choose $t$ to be arbitrarily close to $1$.

Answer (score 2):

[1]. If $r>0$ and $\|y-x\|\leq r$ then $y\in Cl(\{x+s(y-x): s\in [0,1)\})\subset Cl (B(x,r)).$

Because if $U$ is a nbhd of $ y$ then $ B(y,t)\subset U$ for some $t>0,$  and there exists $s\in [0,1)$ such that $\|y-x\|\cdot (1-s)<t. $  Then $$ \|y-(\;x+s(y-x)\;)\|=\|y-x)\|\cdot (1-s)<t$$  so $x+s(y-x)\in B(y,t)\subset U.$

So $y\in Cl(B(x,r)).$

[2]. If $\|y-x\| >r$ then $B(y, \|y-x\|-r)\cap B(x,r)=\emptyset.$ Because if $z\in B(y,\|y-x\|-r)\cap B(x,r)$ then

$\|y-x\|\leq \|y-z\|+\|z-x\|<(\|y-x\|-r)+r=\|y-x\|, $ an absurdity.

So the open set $B(y,\|y-x\|-r)$ contains $y$ and is disjoint from $B(x,r).$

So $y\not \in Cl(B(x,r)). $

Comment: For many basic properties of normed linear spaces, just consider the space $\Bbb R^2$  (with the Cartesian norm) geometrically rather than analytically. and you may see a method that applies to all such  spaces.In \Bbb R^2, for example $B(y, \|x-y\|-r)$ is an open disc disjoint from the open disc $B(x,r)$, and $\{x+s(y-s): 0\leq s<1\}$ is the half-open line segment from $x$ to $y.$

Comment: Sir why? $Cl(\{x+s(y-x): s\in [0,1)\})\subset Cl (B(x,r))$ is because, $\{x+s(y-x): s\in [0,1)\}\subseteq B(x,r)$ since it is convex set. Am i correct?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi. We have $\|y-x\|<r>0$ by hypothesis.  So if $s\in [0,1)$ then the distance from $x$ to $x+s(y-x)$ is $\|s(x-y)\|=|s|\cdot \|x-y\|\le |s|\cdot r<r$ so the vector $x+s(y-x)$ is in the open ball $B(x,r).$

Comment: sir, Got it. Please sir, can you explain one more point? How, $\|y-x\|\leq r$ then $y\in Cl(\{x+s(y-x): s\in [0,1)\}$

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi . For   $∥y−x∥≤ r>0:$ Let $T=\{x+s(y−x):s∈[0,1)\}.$ For $n\in\Bbb N $ let $y_n=x+(1-1/n)(y-x).$ Then $\{y_n:n\in\Bbb N\}\subseteq T$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|y_n-y\|=\lim_{n\to \infty} \|y-x\|/n=0,$ so $y\in\overline T.$